# How to do Facebook Open Graph friendly meta tags with client-side template engines like AngularJS, Mustache, Handlebars

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-opengraph, handlebars.js, mustache

According to my testing, Facebook's crawlers do not render client-side templates like a browser.

I want to avoid a webserver and building HTML files for Open Graph objects at all costs. I want to generate the meta tags on the fly via the URL, but it seems Facebook cannot do this.

Can someone from Facebook please confirm? I asked the head of Open Graph at #mobiledevcon and she said that Facebook can render stuff like {{value}}

My meta tags are as follows, and they render fine in every browser. But the Facebook Open Graph Debugger only sees the raw text, not the interpolated content.

```
<meta property="{{meta.property}}" content="{{meta.content}}">
```

Answer (score 13):

When you think about it it should be clear, why this does not work.

The Facebook crawler downloads the HTML as it is served by the server. The Facebook crawler **will not** execute any JavaScript, like all the crawler will not execute the JavaScript. This is due to security restrictions and for speed reason (they do not have the time execute JavaScript on their servers.)

There is **no way** around this. If you want the crawler to index you page, you need to give them directly what you want them to read.

**Tip:** You could use something like [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) to render your pages on the server side and serve this to the crawlers.

Comment: This answer is spot on. I have written an article about a relatively pain-free work around: http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app/ which does not require phantom.js, only some kind of server-side language (PHP, Ruby, whatever).

Answer (score 4):

[The solution is basically to use some kind of server-side user-agent detection to pick up whenever a social media crawler arrives.](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app)

Answer (score 2):

Use the ?_escaped_fragment_ method along with a prerender service. Facebook will respect the same crawlable Ajax specification as Google. Please see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification