# Open graph issue with AngularJS + Phantom

Tags: angularjs, facebook-opengraph, phantomjs

I am running a setup of [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) AJAX application, and using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and the [Angular-seo](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo) library in order to serve the crawlers with actual mark up instead of JS code.

Unfortunately I am getting an error that says:

`The privacy settings for this attachment prevent you from posting it to this Timeline.`

This seems to be an issue that concerns [many users](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=4624046321981), bu has received no attention whatsoever at the developers community.

My of meta tags, which I must mention that are all filled with the current information from test that I've conducted:

```
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{model.title}}" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{layout.og.description()}}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{layout.og.image()}}" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="{{layout.og.currentUrl()}}" />
```

What could be the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you Inspect those meta tags, even while angular is running, the content attribute is left like that... unlike a ng-bind or something that will replace at runtime.  To circumvent this, I created the following directive:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('ngContent', [
    function() {
      return {
        link: function($scope, $el, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch($attrs.ngContent, function(value) {
                  $el.attr('content', value);
                });
              }
      };
    }
  ])
;
```

Then implemented in the following manner:

```
<meta property="og:description" ng-content="myDescriptionFunction()" />
```

This will create a clean `content="Some description here."` attribute in the meta tag as that content dynamically changes... (watch the element in chrome inspector as you browse) seems to work for me!

Comment: Hello kwhitely, thank you for your time.
That's a good solution, except it doesn't address the problem, the problem is that the crawlers don't run JavaScript at all.

By the way, the only thing that remains as is is a JavaScript expression('referrence', say: user.id), while a code taht is formatted using the Angular template engine it is evaluated to the value of the expression example: {{user.id}}.
COrrect me if I'm wrong, and once again, thank for your time.

Comment: Ahh, well I'm still on the trail hunting for facebook's support of _escaped_fragment_ and such - they do support Fragment escaping, but perhaps only in hashbang urls.  I'm using HTML5 pushstate in my app, so unless it uses google's name="fragment" content="!" meta tag, I may be out of luck... on the backend, I'm using a similar Phantom approach. 

Will update this thread with my findings when I get it sorted.  Hope to have some answer tomorrow if I'm lucky.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is basically to use some kind of server-side user-agent detection to pick up whenever a social media crawler arrives.
http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can't have Angular (or any other front-end js) do that because the Facebook crawler **Doesn't execute javascript**. Therefore, these tags have to be created in the backend (using node.js or php for example)

See [How to do Facebook Open Graph friendly meta tags with client-side template engines like AngularJS, Mustache, Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481731/how-to-do-facebook-open-graph-friendly-meta-tags-with-client-side-template-engin)

Comment: Hi Nicols, I've sovled my issue by this commit: https://github.com/BeOleg/angular-seo/commit/1369e2eb44cfd2bd0e91f74e3122702314c065b1

I also posted this as an answer, but for some reason TheifMaster had deleted it

Comment: this is not true, if you use phantomjs & angularseo (like oleg said he is) you can serve complete html pages to crawlers.