# Phantom js doesn't work for Crawlers (open-graph, google etc) but does work with CURL

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

This is rather a general question, since I am totally new to [PhatomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).
I am using [Angular-seo](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo).

The problem is that the crawler seem to somehow get the the 404 view of my applications, while accessing the link with th`_escaped_fragment_` parameter from the browser or CURL give the needed result.

I am smashing my head into the wall over this for the past several days

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open graph issue with AngularJS + Phantom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426589/open-graph-issue-with-angularjs-phantom)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with the following commit:
https://github.com/BeOleg/angular-seo/commit/1369e2eb44cfd2bd0e91f74e3122702314c065b1

The crawlers were escaping the URL since they were intercepting the '!' mark in my URL