# Facebook is not reading open graph meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, metatag

I am trying to insert dynamic data in fb open graph meta tags. But facebook is not reading the same. This is the url which i am trying to share 
[vkaaotesturl](http://uat.vkaao.com/join-screening-details/VASH/Audi%2002/london-has-fallen/1473363185/fb/0/join)

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook crawler does not interpret JavaScript, dynamic OG tags do not work.

More information: [How to do Facebook Open Graph friendly meta tags with client-side template engines like AngularJS, Mustache, Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481731/how-to-do-facebook-open-graph-friendly-meta-tags-with-client-side-template-engin/16485238#16485238)