# Use the first amp-img on the page for facebook share

Tags: html, share, blogger, amp-html, amp-img

I have a blogger website that I have recently migrated to amp-html.

I am having problems with the usage of `amp-img` tag. Firstly blogger does not recognize the First `amp-img` as the first image of the post and fails to make the default thumbnail out of it.

Also when sharing a page on facebook using `amp-share`, the selected image is invariably the fallback image, that I have tagged with `og:image` property.

The image resolution is more than the minimum mandated by facebook.
I have seen this arrangement working fine on other websites. Can someone please have a quick look here: [Pratyush.info](http://www.pratyush.info/2017/03/india-culture-then-and-now.html)

Comment: Can you share the code for Open Graph Meta tags that you have added in the template? (Mainly with the Blogger data layout tags )

Comment: You have a invalid AMP-html configuration, if you append #development=1 to the url, and the open the console you will see : `http://www.pratyush.info/2017/03/india-culture-then-and-now.html:569:0 The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.`

Comment: @elbaulp perhaps you caught me at the wrong time. I was testing something so it would have been invalid for about half an hour or so. It is valid now.

Comment: @PrayagVerma  <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='Simplicity Silence Surrender' property='og:description'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>

Comment: ...............................................................and most importantly ---    <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-agH78RbEntg/WMFULOdxPMI/AAAAAAAADUI/0zId8itGNnA8GawUbVZqeewxq1DzGumyACLcB/s1600/pratyush.info-default-news.jp' property='og:image'/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days after posting this question I discovered that adding a `noscript` makes the image identifiable by blogger and can be used with data tags. So till google adds some inbuilt support for amp tags, may be this could be what someone is looking for.

```
<noscript><img alt="www.pratyush.info" height="382" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--vp_bO1ozGI/WPegTDKQJDI/AAAAAAAADnQ/FXdCyVKJkTwEj09XneY7csB2Vwd_zVQrQCLcB/milk-protein-intolerance-baby-cow-2160x1200.jpg" title="www.pratyush.info" width="680"></noscript>
```

[DEMO](http://www.pratyush.info/2017/04/intolerance-in-india-as-i-see-it.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your `meta` tag is incorrect, in the link you post is

```
<meta content='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-agH78RbEntg/WMFULOdxPMI/AAAAAAAADUI/0zId8itGNnA8GawUbVZqeewxq1DzGumyACLcB/s1600/pratyush.info-default-news.jp' property='og:image'/>
```

Although the url is an image, the extension is not valid, try to change the name of the image to a valid image extension, like `png` or `jpg`

Comment: The case is opposite of what your observation predicts. If it was the problem, this image should not get loaded , but "pratyush.info-default-news.jp" is infact the image that ALWAYS gets loaded. Nevertheless the way I changed it to .jpg.

Answer (score 1):

The data layout tag `data:post.firstImageUrl` include in the `<head>` tag will always return empty because the the `post` namespace is only defined within the the statement `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>` which is present inside the Blog widget

Instead, you will have to use the data layout tag `data:blog.postImageUrl` in the `og:image` tag to get a high-resolution image. The code will be like -

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

Comment: That was indeed a mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. But I am still not able to get the image in the post to load.  Also I noticed that even standard blogger widgets like "Popular posts" does not show the thumbnails for pages with "amp-img" tag. However both facebook share and the "Popular posts" are able to display thumbnails if i use "img" tag.   I have added a widget at the bottom of the page to demonstrate.

Comment: I checked how your blog looks when it is accessed via google search results. The AMP version does show the post image without issue - Check screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/6FZNvSe.png . The post image is visible without problem from my end.

Comment: The post image is visible but the same image is not being recognized by facebook share or blogger date layout tags when placed in "amp-html". Keeping everything else same, just replacing it with "img" tag - it is recognized everywhere.

Comment: I noticed that the `og:image` tag is still using the fallback image. Have you replaced the Blogger layout tag to `data:blog.postImageUrl` inside the `<head>` tag? Also, the condition wrapping the `og:image` tag would be `<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>` instead of `<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>` .

Comment: <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-agH78RbEntg/WMFULOdxPMI/AAAAAAAADUI/0zId8itGNnA8GawUbVZqeewxq1DzGumyACLcB/s1600/pratyush.info-default-news.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>

Comment: I get the issue now. Because the image is being added to the `amp-img` tag, Blogger is unable to find an image in the post (even though it is present) and the layout tags for fetching the image return empty. The alternative is to insert the `og:image` meta dynamically via JavaScript, but isn't support by Facebook (Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485238/933980 ). Another alternative being that you have to insert the image via the `<img>` tag in the post content but that will make the AMP page invalid

Comment: Exactly. And i think this must be taken up as a bug in blogger now. Is there a way to draw their attention? ( I am very new to blogger)

Comment: It would be quite difficult to raise this issue with Blogger. You can try the official forum or developer forum, but there is no guarantee that they would look into it. Hope they implement AMP for Blogger so that these issues can be resolved.

Comment: @PratyushSrivastava You might be able to do fix this issue by implementing the Facebook SDK and overriding the Share UI Dialog. Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781698/fb-ui-share-set-the-title-message-and-image/33924247#33924247

Comment: I can try to load it in an amp-iframe, Is there any better way to do that.